# Conditional breakpoint in C# being hit every time when value does not match

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2017, conditional-statements

I am debugging a C# project in Visual Studio 2017 and am using a Conditional Breakpoint as follows:

[image]

Clearly the Watch Window shows the condition is not true, however the breakpoint gets hit every time.

Why is this happening, and how do I get it to work as expected and only hit the breakpoint when the CurrentBar value is a multiple of 100?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: CurrentBar is a simple plain integer field or property, without any side effects ? Or is CurrentBar modified with your called functions like `HasValueBeenReached` or within `Add`. If a property is computed, and it's modifying its own value, just to watch it can modify it. The Watch window warns often "evaluation causes side effects" but this warning generation does not discover any dangerous situation.

Comment: CurrentBar is: public int CurrentBar { get; }

Comment: I ended up using:
if (CurrentBar == 2107)
{
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
} 
as I the only reason I was trying to stop every 100 was it wasn't stopping.  Using Debugger.Break() seems way quicker that conditional too.

Comment: But CurrentBar {get;} is a constant. It's not increasing. You are sure there are values dividable by 100 ? However, only scenario I had so far than it stopped to often, was if the evaluation of the expression caused any kind of trouble, raised an exceptions, debugger was unable to evaluate, things like that. In those cases the strategy is; rather stop to often, then not at all. But putting the condition directly in code, is always a good workaround and most reliable.

Comment: You can use [immediate window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/immediate-window?view=vs-2019) to evaluate your condition to set whether it's `true` or not

Comment: @Holger The CurrentBar property gets incremented every time the OnBarUpdate event gets raised, and it gets raised 1000s of times. (the code in the screen shot is in the OnBarUpdateEvent)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, The watch window shows that the condition is not true.

Comment: @user2109254 Then breakpoint will no hit. You should check your code or share with us

Comment: A property defined as {get;} is readonly, it cannot be modified cause it leaks a set accessor. So you are not exact in what you say, you contradict yourself. "often changed" does not mean, increased by 1, "it's in OnBarUpdate" does not mean it's called on every change. You are hiding so many information, and we cannot go through everything by asking verbally.

Comment: @Holger The way the program (NinjaTrader) works is you have a class called a Strategy that runs on a Chart.  The Chart has bars, and when the Strategy loads it iterates over the historical data (Bars) and raises the event OnBarUpdate for each bar, incrementing the CurrentBar value from 0 (the far left bar) by one each bar it moves to the right.  So while in HistoricalData state it is incrementing the bar by one as it moves from left to right over the historical data.
The problem I had is the conditional break point was getting hit every time, instead of only when it is a multiple of 100.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski The problem is the break point is getting hit every time, instead of only when the CurrentBar is a multiple of 100 as the condition suggests.  You can see in the screen shot that he condition is false, but the Conditional Breakpoint is still being hit.  It should only be hit when the condition is true.

Comment: 1) Maybe you have two breakpoints on the line, you would see that on the breakpoints window. That's possible. 2) Hit always is the normal behavior of a disabled condition. But you get notified, if VS disables a condition. 3) you can try putting the same breakpoint with the same condition a few lines before or after, to see what happens. Maybe just this line is weird to the debugger. So you can narrow the problem. But it's just to satisfy curiosity.
You still have not proved to yourself, it's ever dividable by 100. You just said you expect it to be. Debug means: thinking you are wrong. Try %2.